# does nginx have to listen on port 80?

Tags: nginx

I have a node app that uses websockets which is working on local host but not in production.  In production, the messages being posted aren't appearing in the client. Since it's using socket.io, I'm assuming this is a problem with the ports. In production, I'm using nginx with this as the following config. Nginx is listening on port 80 but I have the port for the application at localhost:3000.  Every nginx config I've ever seen has it listening on port 80, and I've heard problems will result if I set localhost below 1000, yet I believe the socket.io is not working because these ports are not the same. Can you suggest how to fix this problem?

/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: The config seems fine, check your error logs and/or your browser console for any errors

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady so you can confirm that nginx doesn't have to listen on 3000 in this situation if localhost is set to 3000?

Comment: your config is not listening on `3000`, it's listening on 80 and proxying to `3000`, I'd say it's only purpose is to be able to use whatever service running on `3000` by calling `example.com` instead of `example.com:3000`